# Glassfish 3.1.2 binding error

Tags: binding, glassfish

Glassfish 3.1.2,
JDevloper 12.1.3, JSF, BC4J
ADF Essential.

JSF page shows no content in Glassfish but shows correct content i Weblogic. The  involved components in JDeveloper seems to be free of errors.

Any ideas to what is wrong - please.

Glassfish log shows:

> Complete Message java.lang.IllegalStateException: The expression
>   "#{bindings.adminTubetypes1.regionModel}" (that was specified for the
>   RegionModel "value" attribute of the region component with id "r1")
>   evaluated to null. This is typically due to an error in the
>   configuration of the objects referenced by this expression. If it
>   helps, the expression "#{bindings.adminTubetypes1}" evaluates to
>   "null". If it helps, the expression "#{bindings}" evaluates to "null".
>   Now using an empty RegionModel instead. at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.getRegionModel(UIXRegion.java:471)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion._beginInterruptibleRegion(UIXRegion.java:766)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.setupChildrenVisitingContext(UIXRegion.java:570)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponent.setupChildrenEncodingContext(UIXComponent.java:1246)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.RegionRenderer._encodeChildren(RegionRenderer.java:1800)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.RegionRenderer.encodeAll(RegionRenderer.java:541)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.component.fragment.UIXRegion.encodeEnd(UIXRegion.java:315)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.taglib.region.IncludeTag$FacetWrapper.encodeAll(IncludeTag.java:568)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.encodeCenterFacet(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:878)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer._encodeCenterPane(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:1299)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer._encodeMiddlePanes(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:350)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.encodeAll(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:315)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeStretchedChild(RichRenderer.java:2367)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelSplitterRenderer._renderPane(PanelSplitterRenderer.java:1637)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelSplitterRenderer.encodeAll(PanelSplitterRenderer.java:315)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.encodeCenterFacet(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:878)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer._encodeCenterPane(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:1299)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer._encodeMiddlePanes(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:350)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.encodeAll(PanelStretchLayoutRenderer.java:315)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:664)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3234)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.PageTemplateRenderer.encodeAll(PageTemplateRenderer.java:68)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:664)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3234)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.FormRenderer.encodeAll(FormRenderer.java:275)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeChild(CoreRenderer.java:647)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeAllChildren(CoreRenderer.java:664)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAllChildrenInContext(RichRenderer.java:3234)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.renderkit.rich.DocumentRenderer.encodeAll(DocumentRenderer.java:1507)
>   at
>   oracle.adf.view.rich.render.RichRenderer.encodeAll(RichRenderer.java:1600)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:525)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.component.UIXComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIXComponentBase.java:1217)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.component.AdfViewRoot.encodeAll(AdfViewRoot.java:102)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:101)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:338)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
>   at
>   javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:170)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:52)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1095)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:389)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:255)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:502)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:327)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>   at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71) at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>   at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to compare the 2 ear files and ensure they contained the same jar files.